# How can I remove the string annotations and keep the values?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
cols = ['DATA']
val = pandas.read_excel('ACC_HAMMER.xlsx' , names = cols)
val.values
main = np.array(val)
print(main)
```

The output I get is as Follows:

```
[['0.00000000E+000,3.82345878E-002,1.80000000E+002']
['1.25000000E+000,1.90616930E-001,-6.71922991E+001']
['2.50000000E+000,9.72069843E-002,7.28934980E+001']
 ..., 
['1.27625000E+003,2.19000920E+000,-1.78028307E+002']
['1.27750000E+003,2.22545238E+000,-1.78318835E+002']
['1.27875000E+003,2.20842885E+000,-1.79763405E+002']]
```

I need to remove the string annotations and sort the data. the first value is x the middle value is a magnitude for y and the last value is a phase. I need the strings removed and 3 lists out.

The excel file has all the values in a single column with a comma seperating them.

Comment: Are you asking how to convert the strings to integers?

Comment: Yes, so far everything I've tried has given me errors.

Comment: If you just use `pandas.read_excel` without names... and `print(val)` what do you get? If your original spreadsheet is three columns with numbers in each... you might find you already have what you want at that point - not sure what you're trying to do by specifying a single name, taking the raw values and then creating a numpy array from it...

Comment: The problem is that they aren't in 3 columns, they are in a single column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pd.read_csv` to read it as a CSV and specify comma as a delimiter.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Changed the file format and changed the code and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is deceptively simple. Python has a function for this. `float(yourstring)`. You can loop over your list of lists and use `split(“,”)` to split them on the comma, then loop over the list returned split and pass them to `float()` and store the returned number in a list.

Comment: why `decimal.Decimal` and not `float`?

Comment: @JonClements to preserve precision.

Comment: Which'd make sense if Excel didn't store values as floats and the precision is as it is - making it Decimal now isn't really doing anything except making it a type that will have to be stored as an object in a numpy array or pandas series and lose out on the benefits of any point of using it with them.